# Замена изображения в зависимости от выбран или не выбран элемент из leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt

Tags: swift

Суть такая надо заменить изображение сердца с пустого на заполнение в зависимости от того был ли выбран элемент из leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt (пока получилось только поменять цвет)вот сам код

`

```
func favoriteActions(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UIContextualAction {
        var object = objects[indexPath.row]
        let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Favorite") { (action, view, completion) in
            object.isFavorite = !object.isFavorite
            self.objects[indexPath.row] = object
            completion(true)
        }
        action.backgroundColor = object.isFavorite ? .systemGray : .systemPurple
        action.image = UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart.fill")
        return action
    }
```

`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ оказался достаточно прост но пока что не могу записать тернарным оператор

```
if object.isFavorite == true{
    action.image = UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart.fill")
} else {
    action.image = UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart")
}
```

Comment: action.image = UIImage(systemName: object.isFavorite ? "suit.heart.fill" : "suit.heart") или action.image = object.isFavorite ? UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart.fill") : UIImage(systemName: "suit.heart")

Comment: А вот как оно записывается тернарным, спасибо. Вечером попробую